# Elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client & elasticsearch-rest-client maven dependency for Elastic server 8.8.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client & elasticsearch-rest-client maven dependency for Elastic server 8.8.2

I have downloaded and using Elastic server 8.8.2 in my localhost.

What are dependencies should be added when using elastic server via spring boot. (using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.2)

Is anyone suggests what are the maven dependencies should be used for **elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client, elasticsearch-rest-client and lucene-core **